# How to match if string contains?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

I have a string variable "distro"

```
let distro = get_distro().unwrap().name;
```

The value of this variable is for example "Arch Linux".
Now i want to check in a match, if the variable contains "arch".

```rust
match distro.to_lowercase() {
  "arch" => //...
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question, it is hard to understand what you are trying to do here

Comment: I tried to improve it, sorry.

Comment: That code would work. What is your issue?

Comment: You can't match substrings, you need to use `if distro.to_lowercase().contains("arch") { ... }`

Comment: Yes it would work, but i want to match more cases (more distros).
=> I dont want many if else branches.

But if its not possible, i accept it. Thank you all! :)

Comment: @jonasrdl you can't! Match will look at the entire result of distro, however you want to match a substring which is found by calling `contains`.

Comment: I try this [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a71697ff1848cd8028900be81f605d22)

Answer (score 6):

To use a condition in a match at rust you need to add an if to your match. In this case it would look like

```rust
match &distro.to_lowercase() {
  x if x.contains("arch") => //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```rust
let distro = get_distro().unwrap().name;

if distro.to_lowercase().as_str().contains("arch") {
    println!("0")
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a1d85c5209e7223894c7d9113dd76cd7)

Also you can make it simpler, like this:

```rust
const DISTRO_NAMES: [&str; 2] = ["arch", "ubuntu"];

fn detector(distro: String) {
    for item in DISTRO_NAMES {
        if distro.to_lowercase().contains(item) {
            println!("the distro is = {item}")
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let distro = get_distro().unwrap().name;

    detector(distro.to_string())
}
```

with this solution, you just need to add your distros to the `DISTRO_NAMES` array.

Comment: Would work, but its not what i want. I dont want to write out the full name, including "linux".

Comment: what about this one?

Comment: would also work, but then I would have many if else branches

Comment: I added new solution to reduce if/else numbers

Answer (score 1):

As per I understand you want to check something in the string. For this purpose, match statement is not quite what you are looking for. For string there exists [`contains`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.contains) method.

Example:

```rust
let disto_name = "Arch Linux";
if distro_name.to_ascii_lowercase().contains("arch") {
    println!("This is arch linux");
} else {
    println!("This is not arch linux");
}
```